# Using strings in Nim with Emscripten causes JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, emscripten, nim-lang, asm.js, webassembly

I'm trying to make a simple Nim app which runs on Emscripten. I'm also using `jsbind` to call a JavaScript function, namely `console.log`.

I have the following file, `test.nim`:

```
import jsbind

type Window* = ref object of JSObj
type Console* = ref object of JSObj

proc getConsole*(): Console {.jsimportgWithName: "function(){return console;}".}

proc log*(c: Console, a: any) {.jsimport.}

echo("Before log")
getConsole().log("Hello")
echo("After log")
```

My `nim.cfg` is:

```
@if emscripten:
  cc = clang
  gc = none
  clang.exe = "emcc"
  clang.linkerexe = "emcc"
  clang.options.linker = ""
  cpu = "i386"
  out = "index.html"
  passC = "-Iemscripten"
  passL = "-Lemscripten -s TOTAL_MEMORY=335544320"
@end
```

I then compile with:

```
nim c -d:emscripten --out=index.html test.nim
```

When I then open `index.html`in a browser and it gets to the `getConsole().log` call, I get numerous console errors about how a function `UTF8ToString` is not defined, and the program terminates:

[image]

This function appears to be an Emscripten prelude function - how do I ensure this and any other functions I need are included in my JavaScript output?

This error occurs both with the WebAssembly options enabled and without. I'm using Nim 0.16.0 and emcc 1.35.0.

Here is a [JSFiddle of the two Emscripten output files](https://jsfiddle.net/y7jfs0mp/). (They are too large for a Stack Snippet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emscripten 1.35.0 is probably too old to have `UTF8ToString` function. Your sample works fine for me with Emscripten 1.37.1.

As a side note, I've noticed you're using fixed Emscripten heap size. In case you want dynamically growing heap you can use `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` flag.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this as soon as I can and accept if it works.

Comment: Is there a Linux binary for 1.37.1 anywhere? I'm having some trouble building with `emsdk` on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen, I haven't found any prebuilt binaries, but here's a script to build emscripten inside a docker image which with some tinkering should likely work in normal linux environment: https://github.com/yglukhov/dockers/blob/master/falcon-pre-nim/innerbuild.sh#L35-L67

Comment: I get: `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/aaron/emscripten-fastcomp" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Comment: This script works for me on macos real env and in docker env: https://gist.github.com/yglukhov/3c9f88c2bf07e834820582c0b36a2e75 . Note that it doesn't run `make install` though. Run `make install` for your own risk =)

Comment: @uran, -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 will produce invalid asm.js and run very slowly on Chrome, does not affect Firefox though.

Comment: @JohnLondon, it works just fine for me in all browsers, even latest IE :)

Comment: @uran see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3907
If V8 decides the code is not valid asm.js, it will run it as if it is just normal js code, no asm.js optimization will apply. So it will work, but slow.

Comment: @JohnLondon, FWIW I describe what I observe with my project. Heap growth doesn't cause any slowdowns. In fact Chrome performs even slightly better than Firefox, even though the heap is reallocated a few times in my project.